# Redis + Socket.io - How to client can join two room the same time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

In my project, I've a user, that user can in two channels , but i want this user can receive notifications for two channels different.

I can ask a question?

**How to Client can join multiple room and receive 2 notifications the same time for different two rooms.**

I have code here :
client.js

```
var socket = io.connect('localhost:3000');
  socket.on('connect', function(){
  socket.emit("subscribe",'test');
});

socket.on('message', function(message) {
   console.log('Receive >>', message);
});
```

server.js

```
var client = redis.createClient();

   io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

      var broadcast = function(channel, message){
      socket.broadcast.to(channel).emit('message', message);
   }

   socket.on("subscribe",function(channel){
       client.subscribe(channel);
       socket.join(channel);
   });

   socket.on('disconnect', function() {
       client.unsubscribe(channel);
       client.removeListener(broadcast)
   })

   client.on("message", broadcast);
});
```

I wanna : `socket.on("subscribe",function(channel){
              client.subscribe(channel, channel1, channel2);
              socket.join(channel, channel1, channel2);
           });`

But socket.io not support that. 
Please give me an idea or a suggestion. Thanks so much!